# Android studio in indexing loop with custom lint rule

Tags: android, android-studio, android-lint

Since I've added a custom lint rule to my project, Android studio sometimes enter "Indexing"/"Updating indices" loop when editing certain files (Java files, although my rule checks XML files).
If I quit all editors, the loop stops.

Re-starting Android Studio seems to help but the issue comes back after some time.

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart